# Merge folders and overwrite contents if conflicts - batch file - windows

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create an "update to latest build" script to pull down the newest data from our server. This looks similar to this:

```
@RD /S /Q "C:\LatestBuild"
set Latest=""
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "somepath\" /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET Latest=%%i
xcopy somepath\%Latest% C:\LatestBuild /s
```

This works excellently when removing all the previous contents first, but I wish to merge other files. The question is, how?

Comment: Remove `rd` and use `xcopy /S /U /Y`? Also check out [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Comment: Using robocopy now as I didn't realise some of the oddities with xcopy. However, this doesn't answer the question about merging

Comment: By merge do you mean just append the content from `somepath\%Latest%` to its version in `C:\LatestBuild` (so just copy it and put it at the end of the existing file)? Or do you mean copy only the differences between those 2 files?